# Sunrise and Sunset times (EDSunriseSet) Objective-C Xcode

Tags: xcode, class

Here I found an interesting link for "EDSunriseSet" but I just can't understand how to use It for my purposes.

In the guide It just say to call this method:

```
+(EDSunriseSet *)sunrisesetWithTimezone:(NSTimeZone *)timezone latitude:(double)lat longitude:(double)longt
```

I imported files and created a EdSunriseSet class

```
EDSunriseSet *albaTramonto;
albaTramonto = [[EDSunriseSet alloc] init];
```

but now I don't know how to get data from that class. Using a tutorial now I can retrive my gps coordinates and now I should send it to that class to receive some data back. Please can you help me understanding how to? I googled but unable to find a guide!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDSunriseSet returning 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23640380/edsunriseset-returning-0)

Check this link. It has the details you want. i had the same problem. Don't alloc and init.
Directly call the method

```
[albaTramonto sunrisesetWithTimeZone:bla bla arguments];
```

and than call the method

```
[albaTramonto calculateSunriseSunset:[NSDate date]];

NSLog(@"Sunrise:%@, Sunset:%@", albaTramonto.localSunrise, albaTramonto.localSunset);
```

This is what i exactly did:

```
NSString *tzStr = @"GMT05:30";


NSTimeZone *tz = [[NSTimeZone alloc] initWithName:tzStr];


EDSunriseSet *edSunriseSet = [EDSunriseSet sunrisesetWithTimezone:tz latitude:19.07283 longitude:72.88261];


[edSunriseSet calculateSunriseSunset:[NSDate date]];


NSLog(@"%@, %@", edSunriseSet.localSunrise, edSunriseSet.localSunset);
```

Comment: Thank you really much! I will try as soon as I can and let you know! :-)

Comment: see the modified answer

Comment: It's Working fine! Now I get sunrise and sunset times thanks for helping!!